# AS3 - Get font Class object for a TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In a mixed Flash IDE/Flex project, I have a TextField and I want to retrieve the Font class object that's associated with that TextField. The TextField lives in a SWF that was created in the CS4 IDE and is loaded into a Flex SWF.

Currently, I have code that works if the following criteria are met:

1. The font is exported in the child SWF's library.
2. The TextField is linked to the exported font.
3. The name of the exported font is hard-coded in the parent SWF.

Code as follows:

```
fontClass = childSwf.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("CustomFont") as Class;
```

What I really want to do is **not** have to know the name of the exported font. Instead, I want to grab either the font's Class or the Class name dynamically from the TextField.

Even better would be the ability to get the Class for built-in fonts without requiring the export.

FWIW, the end goal is to grab any arbitrary TextField and check if it contains characters that its embedded font can't show using Font::hasGlyphs(). However, fonts in child SWFs aren't registered to show up in Font::enumerateFonts().

Answer (score 1):

you can get the text field font name by using `getTextFormat` function of it. Consider `txt` is the textfield, then

```
var format:TextFormat = txt.getTextFormat();
trace(format.font);
```

After some research, I found this solution and it might solve the problem.

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

import flash.text.Font;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var font:Font;
var txt:TextField;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("sub_fla.swf"));

function onLoaded(e:Event){
    var cl:Class = e.currentTarget.applicationDomain.getDefinition("CustomFont") as Class;
    Font.registerFont(cl);
    trace(cl);

    txt = new TextField();
    this.addChild(txt);
    txt.text = "Moorthy";

    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();// = txt.getTextFormat();
    font = new cl();
    format.font = font.fontName;
    txt.setTextFormat(format);

    enumerateFonts();
}

function enumerateFonts(){
    var embeddedFonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(false);
    embeddedFonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);

    trace("---->"+embeddedFonts.indexOf(txt.getTextFormat().font));
    for(var i:int = 0;i<embeddedFonts.length;i++){
        font = embeddedFonts[i];
        trace("embeddedFonts["+i+"]:"+font.fontName+":"+font);  

        if(txt.getTextFormat().font == font.fontName){
            trace("My font class is '"+getQualifiedClassName(font) +"'");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the font to get it in the `enumerateFonts` list. Otherwise it fetches the default font class not your custom class.

Or else, you can simply add a variable to the movieclip (in which the text field is placed) to hold the font class or font class name.

Eg: If `holder` is the movieclip who contains the textfield, then use

`holder.fontClass = cl`

instead of

`Font.registerFont`

and you can simply retrieve the font class by

`txt.parent.fontClass`

If so there is no need of `enumerateFonts` in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Unfortunately this gives me the name of the font (a String) and not the font's associated Class object. I've tried calling getDefinition on the font name and it crashes. Do you know of a way to use this String to get the Class?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you got to about the same place I did. The real question is how to get "CustomFont" without knowing that it's called "CustomFont".

Comment: You can get the `CustomFont` without knowing it by the first way with the help of `enumerateFonts` function and your text field.

Comment: Fonts in child SWFs aren't registered to show up in Font::enumerateFonts().

Comment: In fact, part of your solution is calling registerFont() right after getDefinition() for exactly that reason.

Comment: So this is the case, then trying something like getting all the linkage id's in the library dynamically will help. Will try and let you know if found any thing to resolve the issue.