# How to get font properties of StaticText?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making an flash web app for translating swfs. It [loads](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) a swf file which contains multiple [StaticText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StaticText.html)s. I initially wanted to change the text of those but unfortunately the `text` property is read-only. My solution was to hide them (`visibility = false`) and add [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html)s on their place. I am able to do this but I can't find any way to make new ones look the same. I need to set them the **same font, size and color**.

If you are asking, I have all the fonts used so there shouldn't be any problem with this. Also I have no way to change the original article files to use dynamic text fields.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611689/as3-get-font-class-object-for-a-textfield), this might be a duplicate question. If you can get the `TextFormat` for the original field, then I would assume you can just apply it to the new field. If that answers your questions, please up vote that answer (it needs some love) and we can close this as a dupe :)

Comment: The original field is StaticText not TextField.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I normally program in Flex and thought that "static text" was just some form of a read only TextField :) Now I know better. Good luck in finding an answer (I'm curious now too!).

Comment: You should be able to get most or all of the information you need from the flash.text.TextSnapshot class's getTextRunInfo() method: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextSnapshot.html

Comment: I am afraid StaticText has no getTextSnapshot() method.

Comment: I was able to get `TextSnapshot` from parent `MovieClip` but it gets info for all the contained text elements (`getText()` method returns all texts concatenated). Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible to get the textformat of a static text field programatically.

You can however get the text inside it, or get a bitmap copy of it (in order to get the color)
It shouldn't be possible to get that information unless you dig into the binary code...

However, it might be possible to get that information using some SWF-decompiler. I haven't actually tried that with static texts, but it might be worth a shot since they don't really abide to the rules of what is available through the API :)

Comment: The point of this program is to minimize the effort connected with translating articles. Until now we were using SWF decompiler to get the images and been recreating the entire SWF file which was very long and tiring. This program should let translators to concentrate on the translation only, resulting in quicker and better translations and happier translators.